# Stop Recursive Animation in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I have a recursive animation to make the text on the screen change color. I want some mechanism to stop this animation when the div looses visibility. In my actual site, this is on a dialog box. I want to stop all the animations when the dialog box closes. I tried using `$.stop()` but I don't think that can interrupt the call stack during a recursive call.

Here is the gist of what I'm doing:

javascript:

```
function rainbow() {
    var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
    $('#rainbow ul li').animate({
        color: hue
    }, 500, rainbow);
}
$(function() {
    rainbow();

    $("#stop").click(function() {

        $('#rainbow ul li').stop()

    });
});​
```

html

```
<div id="rainbow">
    <ul>
        <li>Apple</li>
        <li>Microsoft</li>
        <li>SUN</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<button id="stop" type="reset">Stop</button>
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/cRar7/12/

Clicking the Stop button doesn't do anything, the animation continues.

Comment: do not just post links.. provide the code as well incase the third party site goes down!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the first parameter to [.stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

> .stop( [clearQueue] [, jumpToEnd] )
>
> **clearQueue** A Boolean indicating
>   whether to remove queued animation as well. Defaults to false.

So:

```
$('#rainbow ul li').stop(true);
```

should work.

http://jsfiddle.net/cRar7/14/

Comment: Hm I tried `$('#rainbow ul li').stop(true,true);` before posting and that didn't work, however if I use what you posted it does. That `jumpToEnd` parameter must mess things up when dealing with recursion. I guess since there is no "end" there is to way to go to it.

Answer (score 1):

well, you could use a flag  to do the trick :

```
var shouldStop = false;
function rainbow() {
    if(shouldStop) return;
    // rest of animation code here
}

$("#stop").click(function() {
    shouldStop = true;
    $('#rainbow ul li').stop();
});
```

Here's the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/cRar7/13/

Answer (score 0):

If you set an interval instead of setting the animation self recursive it is no problem.
Change your script to this:

```
function rainbow() {
    var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
    $('#rainbow ul li').animate({
        color: hue
    }, 500);
}
$(function() {
    var ani=setInterval(rainbow,500);

    $("#stop").click(function() {

        clearInterval(ani);

    });
});
```